# Limited Connection in Windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6

I get limited connection most times when my WiFi is connected. I have good signal reception but the connection goes as limited every now and then. Even when the connection is not limited, the internet doesn't work showing the error DNS Probe Finished.

What are the possible reasons for this issue? And what is the fix?

I do not have a lot of details about the router as I have not seen the router myself. But the internet is IPv6. I got this information when checking the WAN settings of the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your problem could be due to IPV6 itself. [Remove it from the network settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852)
- Try to find an updated Windows 10 driver for your WLAN-Controller. If you post your PC specifications or Hardware-ID of the WLAN-Controller we could help you with that.
- [Try to change the WiFi Channel](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21132/change-your-wi-fi-router-channel-to-optimize-your-wireless-signal/) in your router's settings. If several people in your neighbourhood use the same channel it could lead to poor performance/disconnects even when the signal quality is good.

Comment: Is it because my laptop doesn't support IPv6? i dont get the internet on my phone as well most times.

Comment: Your laptop supports it, that is not the problem. It's the ISP's and website hosters who screw up the IPv6 protocols. Just, don't use it and deactivate it everywhere you see it. There is no reason to use it in the next years. It's not yet ready to be left out in the wild for normal users.

Comment: If i disable IPv6 will it have any effects on the speed of the internet.. (though it really doesn't matter as the speed that i receive in IPv6 is also horrible)

Comment: It has nothing to do with speed of the internet.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan If you are also having problems with Internet stability on your phone, it indicates there may be a larger problem than just your laptop or Windows 10. You may be diagnosing this improperly. Update your question with that information so we have all the details.

Comment: What sort of diagnostic details are required?